# How to control the same data when adding something in database in ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4, search

Is there any method to control a tables in databases in ASP.NET MVC application? I want to add data, but it should not exist in database before.

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting you can do a query to with `Linq` or `SQL` and see the result if the result exits then inform to user that data already exists if not just in Insert data.
With `Linq` you will compare to `null` object. I hope it will help you. If see your code maybe I can be modre understanding